# Can we make carrier network call by using callkit in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a phone call from my application for that I want to use callkit, it is possible to make a phone call(non VOIP) over carrier network using callkit? so that I can get the call status and last call time.

I am able to make the voip call and also able to see the call log in phone but didn't found a way to read phone call logs.

Comment: No, you can only use a `tel:` URI to make a call via the phone app. No details about the call duration or state will be available to your app

Answer (score 1):

Oops unfortunately not, the only thing you can do is to pass the contact no to the default iOS phone app if you want to make a non-voip call

```
func dialNumber(number : String) {

 if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)"),
   UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
      if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
       } else {
           UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
       }
   } else {
            // add error message here 
   }
}
```

Use this function to make a carrier network call using swift 4.